# saving data and calling data python

Tags: python

say i want to ask the many users to give me their ID number and their name, than save it.
and than i can call any ID and get the name. can someone tell me how i can do that by making a class and using the _ _ init _ _ method?

Comment: Magic?  If you only ask for their ID number and name, how can you know their age :^)

Comment: sorry about that, i wanted to say name..

Comment: @Mark, in South Africa, the first part of the ID number is the birth date. Or what ID number is this?

Answer (score 2):

The "asking" part, as @Zonda's answer says, could use `raw_input` (or Python 3's `input`) at a terminal ("command window" in Windows); but it could also use a web application, or a GUI application -- you don't really tell us enough about where the users will be (on the same machine you're using to run your code, or at a browser while your code runs on a server?) and whether GUI or textual interfaces are preferred, so it's impossible to give more precise advice.

For storing and retrieving the data, a SQL engine as mentioned in @aaron's answer is a possibility (though some might consider it overkill if this is all you want to save), but his suggested alternative of using `pickle` directly makes little sense -- I would instead recommend the shelf module, which offers (just about) the equivalent of a dictionary persisted to disk.  (Keys, however, can only be strings -- but even if your IDs are integers instead, that's no problem, just use `str(someid)` as the key both to store and to retrieve).

In a truly weird comment I see you ask...:

> is there any way to do it by making a
>   class? and using the `__init__`
>   method?

Of course there is a way to do "in a class, using the `__init__` method" most anything you can do in a function -- at worst, you write all the code that would (in a sensible program) be in the function, in the `__init__` method instead (in lieu of `return`, you stash the result in `self.result` and then get the `.result` attribute of the weirdly useless instance you have thus created).

But it makes any sense to use a class only when you **need** special methods, or want to associate state and behavior, and you don't at all explain why either condition should apply here, which is why I call your request "weird" -- you provide absolutely no context to explain **why** you would at all want that in lieu of functions.

If you can clarify your motivations (ideally by editing your question, or, even better, asking a separate one, but **not** by extending your question in sundry comments!-) maybe it's possible to help you further.

Comment: Ok Ok, you caught me on the relational database thing. I was mostly just pulling his/her leg. I am curious about what's wrong with `pickle` though.

Comment: @babikar, it was a valid answer. It's just that it's pretty obvious that you're trying to pawn off a homework assignment on us and you are not being incredibly clear about what you want. This whole `__init__` thing is pretty ridiculous. Do you want the class to model a user or a collection of users? What does 'save' mean in this context? To a file? to a database? for use later in the program? etc. etc. Essentially, ask a serious question and you will get a serious answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a user, use this code (python 3).

```
ID = input("Enter your id: ")
```

In python 2, replace input with raw_input.

The same should can be done to get the users name.

This will save it to a variable, which can be used later in the program. If you want to save it to a file, use the following code:

```
w = open('\path\to\file.txt', 'w')
w.write(ID, age)
w.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're not concerned with security, you can use the pickle module to pickle a dictionary.

```
import pickle

data = {}

# whatever you do to collect the data

data[id] = name
pickle.dump(data, filename)

new_data = pickle.load(filename)
new_name = new_data[id]
#new_name == name
```

otherwise use the sqlite3 module

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (id INTEGER, name TEXT)')

#do whatever you do to get the data

cur.execute('INSERT INTO names VALUES (?,?)', (id, name))


#to get the name later by id you would do...

cur.execute('SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = ?', (id, ))
name = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: is there any way to do it by making a class? and using the _ _ init _ _ method?